# How to stop running an unresponsive script for a CAxWindow -> IWebBrowser2->Navigate

Tags: visual-c++, atl, iwebbrowser2

I am hosting a browser control in an ATL exe using `CAxWindow::CreateControl()`.
Then I query for `IWebBrowser2` interface and Navigate to an URL.
After I call `IWebBrowser2->Navigate`, I do check for

1. `IWebBrowser2->get_ReadyState (&result)` and
2. `IWebBrowser2->get_Busy(&bBusyStatus);`

And based on the above values I call `IWebBrowser2->Stop();`

But if the URL has got some indefinite loop, then script running does not stop and after a while I get the following message:
 `"Stop running this script?
A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly....."`

I want to suppress this message box, monitor for a timeout, show my own custom message and stop running the script. But do not know how to achieve this.
Any help towards this or any alternative idea will be much appreciated.

Note: Even `IWebBrowser2->Quit()` does not help to abort the script.

I'm using VC++, ATL.

Comment: Any quick help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm quite desparte on finding a solution for the above challenge. Please help me.